# How to redirect user from client side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have mvc application.

I want achieve redirection from client side without query string parameters. 
let say I am page http://localhost/weapp/details , from this page I open the open and set startdate, enddate and userid. this pop up also have Go button, when I click on Go button page should redirect
to the page like http://localhost/weapp/userproduectlist with grid filtered by parameter selected in startdate,enddate and userid.

I am using following code to do that. so How to achieve redirection without query string parameters.

```
var start = new Date($('#dtuStartDate').data("kendoDatePicker").value());
  var end = new Date($('#dtuEndDate').data("kendoDatePicker").value());
 $.ajax({
      url:'@Url.Action("Alluserproduectlist","Users")',
     type: 'POST',
     data: { startDate: kendo.toString(start, 'dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt'), endDate: kendo.toString(end, 'dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt'), userid: $("#drpuser").data("kendoMultiSelect")._values.join() },
     success: function(data)
      {
      }
      });
 });
```

so how to redirect in mvc application without query string from one to other action from client with selected parameter so that next page load the data as per the selected parameter in previous page?

Comment: I guest you could try to use cookies instead. Set cookie values (startDate, endDate, userId) on first page then read them in the second one.

Comment: Do a nomal submit (posting the values) and in the POST method, persist the values (e.g. TempData, Session etc) then redirect to the GET method, and in the GET method, read the values (And if your intention is to redirect, its just pointless to be using ajax anyway)

Comment: I suggest if you just want to do it on client side and without using query string, you'd probably want to stop the redirection, stay at the same page, process all the combined code from both controllers in a single controller and display required data one after the another(depending upon user action) using some JavaScript and save the redirection. And each time you need new data, just AJAX it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke- but to redirect to http://localhost/weapp/userproduectlist  with javascript on client side. please refer my attached javascript code.please give suggestion on that also.

Comment: @skiskd, Your current script is an ajax post which stays on the same page. If you want to redirect, then do a normal submit and RedirectToAction - there is no point using ajax. If you don't want the parameters to appear in the url (why not?) then you need to persist them somewhere so they can be read from the `userproduectlist()` GET method. But since the values needed to generate the view are not in the query string, if the user refreshes the view it fails, and the users browser history wont make sense - so its hard to understand why your wanting to do this

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Form with a submit button(GO in your case)

```html
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Alluserproduectlist", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
{
    //set startdate, enddate and userid .
    
    <input type="submit" value="GO"/>
 
}
```

And if you are not Showing a form then pass the values to **hidden  form fields in a form with above mentioned overloads and call jquery $('#myHiddenForm').submit(); on click of go button.**

Answer (score 0):

In your action method you can return the JSON like this:

```
return Json(new { newLocation = "/Home/Index/" });
```

Also you can pass extra information as the result, then in the client side:

```
success: function(data)
{
    window.location = data.newLocation
}
```